# Magento Bundled Product is missing tabs

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, bundled-product

I was following this tutorial http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/ and everything was going smoothly, however I realised that my magento doesn't have a "website" or "bundled item" tab on the left hand side navigator. Is there a setting or something I need to add to make it run?

When I try the tutorial on another Magento website it seems to work fine.

Comment: Hope this would help. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, for the website tab to show up you must have more than one store configured. Some features are hidden for single-view / single-store shops.

In addition to that, the Bundled Items tab is the most critical of all of the tabs as this is where the items are associated to the bundle, making it *a bundle*.

If you are missing this tab, ensure that the product you're editing or creating is truly a bundle product type and not just a simple product (or other type) with a misleading attribute set name.

Comment: how do i tell if it's a proper bundled product type? also could it be possible a plugin is affecting it?

Comment: Create a new product, select Bundle from the product type dropdown. You should then see a tab called 'bundle items'.

Comment: yeah it says "bundled item" for that in the manage product table, and I did select that (I followed the tutorial on my OP)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your product, is that showing product's type as a bundle in product grid.

[image: Product Grid will show product Type]